# Increasing partition of a SD card

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, fsck

I have a SD card that has two partitions `/dev/sdb1` that holds the boot sector, and `/dev/sdb2` that holds the OS. The card still has unpartitioned free space.

How can I take all the unpartitioned free space and add it to `/dev/sdb2` without formatting the drive? I want to do this in on command line only

Comment: See `man resize2fs`.

Comment: The sequence of steps is: 1. resize the partition, using any appropriate tool (`fdisk`, `cfdisk`, `gdisk`, &c.), and 2. resize the filesystem, using `resize2fs` (most likely; there are different tools for different FSs). If you want, you can use `gparted` to do it automatically.

Comment: @goldilocks, I did use `resize2fs` but it says I am already at full block. When I run `parted /dev/sdd/ print free`, I have a whole chunk of Free Space. I want to allocate that to my parition

Comment: Whoops!  You have to increase the *partition* first w/ `fdisk`.  Resize2fs resizes the *filesystem* inside.  I don't have time to write a complete answer right now, but the fdisk thing means "deleting" the partition then creating it again **with the exact same starting block**, but then a greater final size.  It's pretty straightforward, but you may want to look for an intro to fdisk or something if you haven't used it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up using the following. Assuming the disk I want to expand is `/dev/sdd` and has two partitions `/dev/sdd1` and `/dev/sdd2`, and I want to increase `/dev/sdd2`.

```
umount /dev/sdd2
sudo parted /dev/sdd resizepart 2 -- -1
sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdd2
sudo resize2fs /dev/sdd2
```

In this example, I wanted to increase to the maximum volume (hence `-- -1` as argument of `resizepart`. If you want to resize to a specific size, I suggest you first run

```
sudo parted /dev/sdd unit s print free
```

This should print something similar to

```
Number  Start     End        Size       Type     File system  Flags
        63s       2047s      1985s               Free Space
 1      2048s     32767s     30720s     primary  fat16        boot, lba
 2      32768s    5119999s   5087232s   primary  ext2
        5120000s  15728639s  10608640s           Free Space
```

Say you want to expand to sector `10120000s` (that's somewhere between the start/end of my free space `5120000s` to `15728639s`. In that case you run

```
umount /dev/sdd2
sudo parted /dev/sdd resizepart 2 10120000s
sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdd2
sudo resize2fs /dev/sdd2
```